# Columns are not combined when merging two tbl_regression tables

Tags: r, gtsummary

Using `tbl_regression` function in gtsummary package I am trying to stack two linear regression tables. One has an additional column and the other does not. When trying to use the `tbl_merge()` function, two tables are created side-by-side instead of the tables being fully stacked (see image below).

Is there anyway of stacking the two regressions tables, so that the columns are combined and that there is only one of following four columns *Beta*,  *95% CI1*, *p-value*, *p-trend*?

```
# load packages
library(gtsummary)
theme_gtsummary_compact()

# model 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------
# model cyl as a categorical 
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)))
# model cyl as continuous (p-trend)
mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

# summarize primary model
tbl1 <- tbl_regression(mod1)
# summarize model with p-trend, and hide the estimate and CI
tbl2 <- tbl_regression(mod2) %>%
  modify_table_header(c(estimate, ci), hide = TRUE) %>%
  modify_header(p.value ~ "**p-trend**")

# merge primary model and p-trend
tbl3 <- tbl_merge(list(tbl1, tbl2)) %>%
  # remove spanning header
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA)


# model 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------

# model cyl as a categorical 
mod3 <- lm(mpg ~ carb, data = mtcars)

# summarize primary model
tbl4 <- tbl_regression(mod3) %>%
  # remove spanning header
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA)


# merge model 1 and 2 ------------------------------------------------------
bl3 <- tbl_merge(
  tbls = list(tbl3, tbl4)
  )

bl3
```

[image]

Comment: Use `gtsummary::tbl_stack()`, both to build `tbl3` and `bl3`

Comment: @meriops if I use  `gtsummary::tbl_stack()`  for `tbl3`, I lose the p-trend column.

Comment: Stack all your regression model tables, before you merge the ptrend.

Comment: This issue I think you're experiencing is because the underlying column names are changed after your first merge. Therefore, when you stack the last table, the column names are different and the table wouldn't look nice or as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Daniel. It makes sense. The difficulty I am having is that I am merging a serious of stratified tables then stacking various variables on top of each other - so it is much more complex than I can demonstrate using the above example. So stacking before merging does not seem to work for me here. Is it perhaps possible to report p-trend for all variables (having a p-trend column for all) then hiding the p-trend for variables that this is not relevant?